# How do i fix overlapping fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a top bar and a bottom bar. I want to go to certain places from the top menu and to certain places from the bottom menu. But these two parts overlap each other, how can I solve this in the fragment. I make Twitter-style bottom and top components, but the fragment is overwritten.

I searched for fragment removal code but I couldn't find it.

Can you tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks.

**FeedActivity2.kt**

```
package com.ager.sutra

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import com.ager.sutra.databinding.ActivityFeed2Binding
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import com.ager.sutra.fragments.HomeFragment
import com.ager.sutra.fragments.MessageFragment
import com.ager.sutra.fragments.ProfileFragment
import com.ager.sutra.fragments.SearchFragment


class FeedActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding : ActivityFeed2Binding
private lateinit var fragmentLane : Fragment
private val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
private val searchFragment = SearchFragment()
private val messageFragment = MessageFragment()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityFeed2Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)



    val drawerLayout : DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)

    binding.imageMenu.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START) })

    val navView : NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)


    val navController : NavController = 
    Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.navHostFragment)

    try {
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController)
    }catch (e : Exception){
        println(e.localizedMessage)
    }



    val bottomNav = binding.bottomNavigation
    bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.bottom_home -> makeCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
            R.id.bottom_search -> makeCurrentFragment(searchFragment)
            R.id.bottom_messages -> makeCurrentFragment(messageFragment)
        }
        true
    }


}

private fun makeCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply{
        replace(R.id.navHostFragment, fragment)
        commit()
    }

}
```

**activity_feed2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
tools:context=".FeedActivity"
>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/darkGray"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageMenu"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24"
            app:tint="@color/white" />
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutToolBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost = "true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main"
        app:background="@color/darkGray"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkGray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemIconSize="24dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_itemselector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        >

    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**main.xml** (Navigation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:name="com.ager.sutra.fragments.HomeFragment"
    android:label="Home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
    android:name="com.ager.sutra.fragments.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="Profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
    android:name="com.ager.sutra.fragments.SettingsFragment"
    android:label="Settings"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/messageFragment"
    android:name="com.ager.sutra.fragments.MessageFragment"
    android:label="Message"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_message" />
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup all over NavigationController.
Magic happens down below =)

```
setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

Also, don't forget about OnSupportNavigateUp to handle drawer layout icon clicks

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```